# class member variable and "Queries with local collections are not supported"

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a List that serves as the source of the IN operator.  The typical linq-to-sql query:

```
public void foo()
{
   var inThisListOnly = new string[] { "VA", "MA" };

   var result = (
       from o in Orders
       where inThisListOnly.Contains(o.State)
       select o
   )
   .ToDictionary( o => o.Id, o => o );
}
```

everything works fine.  I want to save a few CPU cycles by moving inThisListOnly outside of foo to become a member variable of the class.

```
public class FooClass
{
    private readonly string[] _inThisListOnly = new string[] { "VA", "MA" };

    public void foo()
    {
        var result = (
          from o in Orders
          where _inThisListOnly.Contains(o.State)
          select o
        )
        .ToDictionary( o => o.Id, o => o );
    }
}
```

After the modifiction, my program starts to throw the notorious "Queries with local collections are not supported" exception.  Would anyone provide an explanation to the behavior?  In some sense, isn't _inThisListOnly less local than inThisListOnly?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to show what you're doing with the query. As it stands, what you have shown won't throw in any circumstance because you never iterate over the query.

Comment: The next step is iteration.  I put the result into a Dictionary.

Comment: @Candy no repro! http://ideone.com/RG6Pz

Comment: @Bala R I can reproduce this every time. Candy, I have no idea though... it's an odd one.

Comment: @BalaR you are not using LINQ to SQL but rather LINQ to Objects

Comment: @MarkSowul How do I convert this to Linq to SQL?

Comment: Convert what to L2S?  I'm simply saying that Bala's code is not a repro because it is not using L2S.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of Order collection? Is it local enumerable or linq to sql provided table?

Comment: Orders is a linq to sql provided table - DatabaseContext.Orders.

Comment: I didnt manage to reproduce your error :( Everything runs fine

Comment: There are existing topics on this issue...check them!

Comment: Please post a link.  I couldn't find any reference.